# .net-core Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, asp.net-core

I have a Generic repository which I want to register for DI, it implements an interface IRepository.

Normally I would create an instance of it like this:

```
IRepository repo = new Repository<Order>();
```

However I am trying to get up to speed in .net 5 ahead of release and want to get this working with DI, I have resorted to the following :

```
services.AddTransient<DAL.IRepository<Models.Order>, DAL.Repository<Models.Order>>();
```

But this feels wrong, I don't want 50+ lines in there one for each of the classes in my model...

I cannot find anything online about this, I know its possible with other ioc containers.. but as this is a learning project I dont want to use another container, Im aiming to do it all with .net5s native container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some back and forwards in the comments to other answers I have a working solution, It might not be the best way but it works. Ill update again if I find a better way to implement this.

The two issues I had were : Needed to register a generic interface, the issue here was a lapse in concentration on my part.. I had the syntax wrong for registering a generic type which of course is :

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

The second issue was that I have an assembly which contains 50+ different models which I wanted registered, The way that I addressed this was to write a method that I can pass a list of assemblies to along with the Namespace that I want to register and it iterates over any types that match the criteria and registers them in the DI container.

```
public void RegisterModels(IServiceCollection services, string[] Assemblies, string @NameSpace)
    {
        foreach (var a in Assemblies)
        {
            Assembly loadedAss = Assembly.Load(a);

            var q = from t in loadedAss.GetTypes()
                    where t.IsClass && !t.Name.Contains("<") && t.Namespace.EndsWith(@NameSpace)
                    select t;

            foreach (var t in q.ToList())
            {
                Type.GetType(t.Name);
                services.AddTransient(Type.GetType(t.FullName), Type.GetType(t.FullName));
            }
        }
    }
```

This is then called from the startup.cs method ConfigureServices :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<TestContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;"));

        services.AddMvc();

        RegisterModels(services, new string[] { "UI" }, "UI.Models");

        services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
    }
```

There may be a better way to do this, there definitely is using different DI containers, if anyone has improvements to offer please let me know.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something. Why do you need to register your viewmodels using DI?

Comment: You are quite right, the original problem was that I wasn't able to register the generic repository without specifying a type, which led me down a bit of a path where it was suggested that this is not possible in the .net 5 DI container - so I started looking at ways to minimize the work to register all of the different types of generic repo that I would need... However you are correct, The RegisterModels method is not needed - Ive left it in as it may be useful to others looking to register a number of classes within a namespace, Ill edit to make that clearer.

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to register the open generic with

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a convention based registration library like [Scrutor](http://kristian.hellang.com/introducing-scrutor/).

Scrutor is a small open source library that provides a fluent API to register services in your Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection container based on conventions (Similar to Autofac's RegisterAssemblyTypes method, StructureMap's Scan method and Ninject's Conventions package).

This will allow you to do something like this:

```
services.Scan(scan => scan
            .FromAssemblies(<<TYPE>>.GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
                .AddClasses(classes => classes.Where(x => {
                    var allInterfaces = x.GetInterfaces();
                    return 
                        allInterfaces.Any(y => y.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && y.GetTypeInfo().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRepository<>)));
                }))
                .AsSelf()
                .WithTransientLifetime()
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an extension method to encapsulate all those individual items that need to be registered.

That is the same technique Microsoft is using, for example you only put this in startup:

```
services.AddMvc();
```

but that is an extension method and behind the scenes you can bet it is registering a bunch of stuff it needs.

so you can create your own extension method like this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
public static IServiceCollection AddMyFoo(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<DAL.IRepository<Models.Order>, DAL.Repository<Models.Order>>();
    //....

    return services;
}
```

and by making the method return the IServiceCollection you make it fluent so you can do

```
services.AddMyFoo().AddSomeOtherFoo();
```

Updated based on comment

the other technique to reduce registrations is when your dependency doesn't itself have dependencies you can make the constructor have a default of null so you still have decoupling and could pass a different one in later but the DI won't throw an error and you can just instantiate what you need if it is not passed in.

```
public class MyFoo(IFooItemDependency myItem = null)
{
    private IFooItemDependency internalItem;

    public MyFoo(IFooItemDependency myItem = null)
    {
        internalItem = myItem ?? new FooItemItem();
    }
}
```

Comment: That still requires me to register 50+ repositories, its just moving the code to do so somewhere else...

If Im going to do that then I might as well get rid of the generic repository.

To clarify I want to do have (if possible) one line to register the repo, regardless of what type its concrete implementation will be.

Comment: just updated my answer with something that may help, but ultimately nothing can be passed in unless it is registered somewhere, there is no auto discovery by reflection. Note that you don't have to use the built in DI so if some other compatible DI supports auto register you could use it, but that is not a feature of the built in DI

Comment: That's what I was thinking.. Thanks for confirming. As much as I didn't want to use anything else I'll use another IOC container.

Comment: @D3vy - You have to understand that IoC doesn't do your work for you.  Yes, it moves the registration somewhere else, but you still have to do the registration.  The point of moving it somewhere else is that it facilities testability, discoverability, and enforces dependency segregation, all of which lead to better code, not that it makes you less work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what your question is I assume you don't want to have

```
services.AddTransient<DAL.IRepository<Models.Order>, DAL.Repository<Models.Order>>();
services.AddTransient<DAL.IRepository<Models.Person>, DAL.Repository<Models.Person>>();
services.AddTransient<DAL.IRepository<Models.Invoice>, DAL.Repository<Models.Invoice>>();
```

etc

I have done this before (with ninject)

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>)).InRequestScope();
```

I imagine for Unity you can do something similar like

```
services.AddTransient<DAL.IRepository<>, typeof(Repository<>)();
```

And then to use it in a service

```
public OrderService(IRepository<Models.Order> orderRepository)
{
    this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
}
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by OP the correct syntax is:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

Comment: sadly `services.AddTransient<DAL.IRepository<>, typeof(Repository<>)();` is not valid code and the question is not about Unity.

Comment: My bad about mentioning Unity, but it's not unity code anyway.

Are there any errors? Runtime? Build time?

Comment: I've not typed it in to VS but can see 3 problems from here that will all fail to compile: 1. there are more `<`'s than `>`'s. 2. you can't put `typeof(Repository<>)` between `<` and `>` and 3. you can't place an open generic type like `DAL.IRepository<>` between `<` and `>` (you would need something like `AddTransient(typeof(DAL.IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>)`)

Comment: you know copy paste is an option these days?

Here it is (as I said, it may work. I mean at least try right?)
services.AddTransient<DAL.IRepository<>, typeof(Repository<>)>();

Comment: Sarcasm it not really a great way to interact, I'm only trying to help. It won't compile.

Comment: Sorry qujck, thought you were OP

Comment: @qujck Thanks for the edit on my answer, posted via the SO android app and find the interface a little lacking.

Anyway, one of your comments above sent me down the right track, the issue was me using the incorrect syntax (Attempting to place an open generic type between < > ) the correct syntax as you pointed out was: services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>)); if you want to put that into an answer Ill flag it as being correct. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @D3vy The interface on Windows Phone is also terrible!