# Factory Pattern with Open Generics

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core, one of the things you can do with Microsoft's dependency injection framework [is bind "open generics"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342472/net-core-dependency-injection) (generic types unbound to a concrete type) like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>))
}
```

You can also employ [the factory pattern to hydrate dependencies](http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2016/05/09/asp-net-core-factory-pattern-dependency-injection/). Here's a contrived example:

```
public interface IFactory<out T> {
    T Provide();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IFactory<>), typeof(Factory<>));

    services.AddSingleton(
        typeof(IRepository<Foo>), 
        p => p.GetRequiredService<IFactory<IRepository<Foo>>().Provide()
    ); 
}
```

However, I have not been able to figure out how to combine the two concepts together. It seems like it would start with something like this, but I need the concrete type that is being used to hydrate an instance of `IRepository<>`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IFactory<>), typeof(Factory<>));

    services.AddSingleton(
        typeof(IRepository<>), 
        provider => {
            // Say the IServiceProvider is trying to hydrate 
            // IRepository<Foo> when this lambda is invoked. 
            // In that case, I need access to a System.Type 
            // object which is IRepository<Foo>. 
            // i.e.: repositoryType = typeof(IRepository<Foo>);

            // If I had that, I could snag the generic argument
            // from IRepository<Foo> and hydrate the factory, like so:

            var modelType = repositoryType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var factoryType = typeof(IFactory<IRepository<>>).MakeGenericType(modelType);
            var factory = (IFactory<object>)p.GetRequiredService(factoryType);

            return factory.Provide();
        }           
    ); 
}
```

If I try to use the `Func<IServiceProvider, object>` functor with an open generic, I get [this `ArgumentException`](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/15bda756314f70cce0f6025f6ef8defab3617cfa/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceLookup/ServiceTable.cs#L35) with the message `Open generic service type 'IRepository<T>' requires registering an open generic implementation type.` from the dotnet CLI. It doesn't even get to the lambda.

Is this type of binding possible with Microsoft's dependency injection framework?

Comment: What is the advantage of registering a lambda that resolves a factory that resolves the required service?

Comment: Good question. It reroutes complexity for conditional hydration. You don't need an explicit factory since the lambda acts as one (its variable is even called the "implementationFactory"), but if you need several services to make a decision on what instance you want to hydrate, you're going to have a  lambda that is complex and hard to test. The blog post I linked above has a good example: http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2016/05/09/asp-net-core-factory-pattern-dependency-injection/

Comment: did you ever find a good answer for this? I have the same issue, but none of the answers here seem to be a good solution for the problem

Comment: We "solved" the problem by closing the generics before service registration. I wrote it up in this GitHub issue. https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/498#issuecomment-291926999

Comment: IMHO, the real solution is to not use Microsoft's DI container. They've stated they aren't going to solve this problem in this GitHub thread. https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/474#issuecomment-276233672

Answer (score 31):

The net.core dependency does not allow you to provide a factory method when registering an open generic type, but you can work around this by providing a type that will implement the requested interface, but internally it will act as a factory. A factory in disguise:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMongoCollection<>), typeof(MongoCollectionFactory<>)); //this is the important part
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>))

public class Repository : IRepository {
    private readonly IMongoCollection _collection;
    public Repository(IMongoCollection collection)
    {
        _collection = collection;
    }

    // .. rest of the implementation
}

//and this is important as well
public class MongoCollectionFactory<T> : IMongoCollection<T> {
    private readonly _collection;

    public RepositoryFactoryAdapter(IMongoDatabase database) {
        // do the factory work here
        _collection = database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name.ToLowerInvariant())
    }

    public T Find(string id) 
    {
        return collection.Find(id);
    }   
    // ... etc. all the remaining members of the IMongoCollection<T>, 
    // you can generate this easily with ReSharper, by running 
    // delegate implementation to a new field refactoring
}
```

When the container resolves the MongoCollectionFactory it will know what type T is and will create the collection correctly. Then we take that created collection save it internally, and delegate all calls to it. ( We are mimicking `this=factory.Create()` which is not allowed in csharp. :))

Update:
As pointed out by Kristian Hellang the same pattern is [used by ASP.NET Logging](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/2d2f31968229eddb57b6ba3d34696ef366a6c71b/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerOfT.cs#L29)

```
public class Logger<T> : ILogger<T>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Logger(ILoggerFactory factory)
    {
        _logger = factory.CreateLogger(TypeNameHelper.GetTypeDisplayName(typeof(T)));
    }

    void ILogger.Log<TState>(...)
    {
        _logger.Log(logLevel, eventId, state, exception, formatter);
    }
}
```

original discussion here:

https://twitter.com/khellang/status/839120286222012416

Comment: I think more appropriate name for `MongoCollectionFactory` would be `CollectionProxy`=)) because it doesn't implement any `CreateCollection` like method. And with new name it will be easier to understand the real purpose of this class))

Answer (score 5):

See this [issue on the dotnet (5) runtime git](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41050).
This will add support to register open generics via a factory.

Comment: This issue is still open! :-|

Answer (score 3):

I was dissatisfied with the existing solutions as well.

Here is a full solution, using the built-in container, that supports everything we need:

- Simple dependencies.
- Complex dependencies (requiring the `IServiceProvider` to be resolved).
- Configuration data (such as connection strings).

We will register a proxy of the type that we really want to use. The proxy simply inherits from the intended type, but gets the "difficult" parts (complex dependencies and configuration) through a separately registered `Options` type.

Since the `Options` type is non-generic, it is easy to customize as usual.

```
public static class RepositoryExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A proxy that injects data based on a registered Options type.
    /// As long as we register the Options with exactly what we need, we are good to go.
    /// That's easy, since the Options are non-generic!
    /// </summary>
    private class ProxyRepository<T> : Repository<T>
    {
        public ProxyRepository(Options options, ISubdependency simpleDependency)
            : base(
                // A simple dependency is injected to us automatically - we only need to register it
                simpleDependency,
                // A complex dependency comes through the non-generic, carefully registered Options type
                options?.ComplexSubdependency ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options)),
                // Configuration data comes through the Options type as well
                options.ConnectionString)
        {
        }
    }

    public static IServiceCollection AddRepositories(this ServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
    {
        // Register simple subdependencies (to be automatically resolved)
        services.AddSingleton<ISubdependency, Subdependency>();

        // Put all regular configuration on the Options instance
        var optionObject = new Options(services)
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionString ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString))
        };

        // Register the Options instance
        // On resolution, last-minute, add the complex subdependency to the options as well (with access to the service provider)
        services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider => optionObject.WithSubdependency(ResolveSubdependency(serviceProvider)));

        // Register the open generic type
        // All dependencies will be resolved automatically: the simple dependency, and the Options (holding everything else)
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(ProxyRepository<>));

        return services;

        // Local function that resolves the subdependency according to complex logic ;-)
        ISubdependency ResolveSubdependency(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return new Subdependency();
        }
    }

    internal sealed class Options
    {
        internal IServiceCollection Services { get; }

        internal ISubdependency ComplexSubdependency { get; set; }
        internal string ConnectionString { get; set; }

        internal Options(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            this.Services = services ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fluently sets the given subdependency, allowing to options object to be mutated and returned as a single expression.
        /// </summary>
        internal Options WithSubdependency(ISubdependency subdependency)
        {
            this.ComplexSubdependency = subdependency ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(subdependency));
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also don't understand the point of your lambda expression so I'll explain to you my way of doing it.

I suppose what you wish is to reach what is explained in the article you shared

> This allowed me to inspect the incoming request before supplying a dependency into the ASP.NET Core dependency injection system

My need was to inspect a custom header in the HTTP request to determine which customer is requesting my API. I could then a bit later in the pipeline decide which implementation of my `IDatabaseRepository` (File System or Entity Framework linked to a SQL Database) to provide for this unique request.

So I start by writing a middleware

```
public class ContextSettingsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ContextSettingsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IHostingEnvironment env, IContextSettings contextSettings)
    {
        var customerName = context.Request.Headers["customer"];
        var customer = SettingsProvider.Instance.Settings.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == customerName);
        contextSettings.SetCurrentCustomer(customer);

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

My `SettingsProvider` is just a singleton that provides me the corresponding customer object.

To let our middleware access this `ContextSettings` we first need to register it in `ConfigureServices` in Startup.cs

```
var contextSettings = new ContextSettings();
services.AddSingleton<IContextSettings>(contextSettings);
```

And in the `Configure` method we register our middleware

```
app.UseMiddleware<ContextSettingsMiddleware>();
```

Now that our customer is accessible from elsewhere let's write our Factory.

```
public class DatabaseRepositoryFactory
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _env { get; set; }

    public Func<IServiceProvider, IDatabaseRepository> DatabaseRepository { get; private set; }

    public DatabaseRepositoryFactory(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
        DatabaseRepository = GetDatabaseRepository;
    }

    private IDatabaseRepository GetDatabaseRepository(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var contextSettings = serviceProvider.GetService<IContextSettings>();
        var currentCustomer = contextSettings.GetCurrentCustomer();

        if(SOME CHECK)
        {
            var currentDatabase = currentCustomer.CurrentDatabase as FileSystemDatabase;
            var databaseRepository = new FileSystemDatabaseRepository(currentDatabase.Path);
            return databaseRepository;
        }
        else
        {
            var currentDatabase = currentCustomer.CurrentDatabase as EntityDatabase;
            var dbContext = new CustomDbContext(currentDatabase.ConnectionString, _env.EnvironmentName);
            var databaseRepository = new EntityFrameworkDatabaseRepository(dbContext);
            return databaseRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

In order to use `serviceProvider.GetService<>()` method you will need to include the following using in your CS file

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

Finally we can use our Factory in `ConfigureServices` method

```
var databaseRepositoryFactory = new DatabaseRepositoryFactory(_env);
services.AddScoped<IDatabaseRepository>(databaseRepositoryFactory.DatabaseRepository);
```

So every single HTTP request my `DatabaseRepository` will may be different depending of several parameters. I could use a file system or a SQL Database and I can get the proper database corresponding to my customer. (Yes I have multiple databases per customer, don't try to understand why)

I simplified it as possible, my code is in reality more complex but you get the idea (I hope). Now you can modify this to fit your needs.

Comment: This seems is a little different from my problem, though it is a very good example of how to delay definitions for `IServiceCollection` on a per-request basis. You are deferring the decision on which implementation of a known type (`IDatabaseRepository`) to use. In my situation, `IRepository<>` is open/unknown because I do not have the type information necessary on how to close it in the `implementationFactory` lambda for `ServiceProvider`.

Comment: Just to clarify some things. You can ALWAYS get rid of lambda expressions. They are just here to simplify developers life and allows us to code quicker. But in that case I didn't like to have this big piece of code inside my Startup.cs file. That's why I chose to get rid of it and implement my logic in a `DatabaseRepositoryFactory`. You can also do the same if you wish.

Comment: Also my database repositories actually implement `IDatabaseRepository<IDatabase>`, interface that actually inherits from `IRepository<T>`. So my real dependency injection is `services.AddScoped<IDatabaseRepository<IDatabase>>(databaseRepositoryFactory.DatabaseRepository)`. I thought it was a good idea to simply that in my example but maybe you needed the full sample... It does not matter that I don't chose what implementation of `IDatabase` I use. My repository just has to respect its contract and accepts or returns some `IDatabase`.

Comment: Why the middleware? Inspect the header when creating the service instead. I would suggest you skip the mix of Settings.Instance service locator pattern to provide info for the DI.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Fundamental Theorem of Software Engineering: "We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection."

This worked for me:

```cs
internal class RepositoryFactory<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> _repository;

    public RepositoryFactory<T>(IFactory<IRepository<T>> factory)
    {
        _repository = factory.Provide();
    }

    // implement IRepository<T> here, with passthroughs to _repository.
}
```

Although it sucks if you have a lot of open generics to register, it gets around the problem where you can't currently register an open generic with a factory implementation on the `IServiceCollection`.

FWIW, I'd recommend doing the registration as either scoped or transient instead of singleton.

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(RepositoryFactory<>));
```