# C# asp.net core generic factory method dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, repository-pattern

I am using asp.net core, when adding my service to dependency injection i have a following scenario:

```
        // TODO Need to have generalized code for following Repositories
        services.AddScoped(s => s.GetRequiredService<IRepositoryFactory>().CreateRepository<Customer>(services));
        services.AddScoped(s => s.GetRequiredService<IRepositoryFactory>().CreateRepository<CustomerCategory>(services));
        services.AddScoped(s => s.GetRequiredService<IRepositoryFactory>().CreateRepository<SaleOrder>(services));
```

In this case i am mentioning "T" explicitly which will be headache when model grows, my CreateRepository method is as follows:

```
    public IRepository<T> CreateRepository<T>(IServiceCollection services) where T : class 
    {

        if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IAuditable)))
            return _provider.GetRequiredService<AuditableRepository<T>>();
        else if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IArchivable)))
            return _provider.GetRequiredService<ArchivableRepository<T>>();

        //return new Repository<T>(_provider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>());
        return _provider.GetRequiredService<Repository<T>>();
    }
```

I want some thing like:

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped(typeof(IRepository<>), s.GetRequiredService<IRepositoryFactory>().CreateRepository<>(services)));
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? If so, you don't need repository pattern at all. Skip that and write services.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Factory Pattern with Open Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029344/factory-pattern-with-open-generics)

Answer (score 0):

One solution you can use here is to implement generic base classes for your controllers. In your generic controller base you can set a property to hold your repository. This works nicely when using ASP.Net Core as a web API.