# How to register a generic service with parameters

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection

I have a generic service that I register like this:

```cs
serviceProvider.AddSingleton(typeof(IMyService<>), typeof(MyService<>));
```

That works great. It injects the service with T = the class that it gets injected to. So far so good.

```cs
public class MyService<T> : IMyService<T>
{
  public MyService(string myParameter)
  {
    // do something with T and myParameter.
  }
}
```

Now I want to pass a parameter to the contructor at time of registration.

How do I pass a paramter to a generic service?

Does something like below code exist?

```cs
serviceProvider.AddSingleton(typeof(IMyService<>), typeof(MyService<>), "SomeStringValue");
```

If not what is the best work around?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Factory Pattern with Open Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029344/factory-pattern-with-open-generics)

Comment: You might want to look at the Options pattern. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to create and pass a hard-coded value into the constructor of a service. Why not put that value into something that you can change in the future if the need arises, like appsettings.json files, then inject the entire IConfigurationRoot into the service, or specific sections of the configuration using the IOptions construct?

In my applications, I have a set of strongly-typed configuration classes that can be parsed from the appsettings of the applications. The first lines of my Program.cs file are:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
   .AddJsonFile(
        $"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json",
        true, true)
   .AddEnvironmentVariables()
   .Build();

builder.Services.AddSingleton(configuration);

var appConfiguration = new ApplicationConfiguration();
configuration.Bind("ApplicationConfiguration", appConfiguration);
builder.Services.Configure<ApplicationConfiguration>(configuration.GetSection("ApplicationConfiguration"));
```

I then either inject an IOptions into services or controllers, or I extract them from an injected IServiceProvider. Either case, the .Value of the IOptions is the instance of the ApplicationConfiguration class.

Answer (score 2):

Primitive values such as strings and ints can't easily be registered in the container, because their meaning is ambiguous. The the following would not really work:

```cs
// Would not really work
services.AddSingleton("SomeStringValue");
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMyService<>), typeof(MyService<>));
```

But you can't register a delegate either with the open generic type:

```cs
// Would certainly not work
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMyService<>),
     sp => new MyService<???>("SomeStringValue"));
```

So instead, you could register each closed type individually:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IMyService<A>>(new MyService<A>("SomeStringValue"));
services.AddSingleton<IMyService<B>>(new MyService<B>("SomeStringValue"));
```

But this might not be convenient, especially if you have many different closed versions, or when new versions are added regularly.

The best solution in this case is, IMO, to remove the ambiguity that strings cause and wrap that string in a wrapper class that can be registered:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(new MyServiceSettings("SomeStringValue"));
// Here, MyService<T> now depends on MyServiceSettings rather than string
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMyService<>), typeof(MyService<>));
```

This requires you to change the constructor of `MyService<T>` to accept a `MyServiceSettings` instead of a `string`:

```cs
public class MyService<T> : IMyService<T>
{
  private readonly MyServiceSettings settings;
  public MyService(MyServiceSettings settings)
  {
    this.settings = settings;
  }

  // use settings.SomeStringValue in the class
}
```

Besides directly injecting the `MyServiceSettings`, ASP.NET Core also allows you to supply an `IOption<MyServiceSettings>` to the constructor. This is what @Ralf refers to in the comments. As I see it, however, this only leads to extra complexity, because in this case you would be injecting an interface that allows access to the `MyServiceSettings` parameter object. That's just an extra level of indirection that is in most cases not needed. Still, it's good to know this option exist. It's good to understand the options and know what their benefits, downsides and consequences are.